# Flutter java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat;

Tags: flutter, crash, android-appcompat, androidx, noclassdeffounderror

When upgrading Flutter from version 2.5.3 to 2.8.1. I get this error and the app crashes. The app does compile and the main screen does appear for a split second but then it crashes and disappears. I have migrated the project to androidX. I have also updated the DartSDK version to 2.15.1.
Thank you for your help!